# Memory trouble when deallocating Fortran linked list,

Tags: list, memory, linked-list, fortran

I have implemented a generic linked list (genII.f90) written in Fortran found in 
http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Linked+list  .

I test it and everything is ok except the fact that  the LI_Remove_Head function seems not to free the memory.

I add to the original module  the function LI_Destruct (see below) and same result it does not free the memory.

```
SUBROUTINE LI_Destruct(List)  
implicit none
TYPE(List_Type),INTENT(INOUT),TARGET :: List
TYPE(Link_Ptr_Type) :: Link_current, Link_next

Link_next%P =>List%Head%next


do while (associated(Link_next%P))
    Link_current%P => Link_next%P

    Link_next%P => Link_next%P%next
    deallocate(Link_current%P)
end do
end subroutine LI_destruct
```

I certainly miss something so my questions are two:
1- Is there an error in the code? For what reason the memory is not emptied by the "deallocate"?

2- Does it exist better and almost standard generic linked list for fortran?

I add the simple code below used to do the test:

```
PROGRAM test_list

! Defines data and other list(s) and arrays for particles. 

USE Generic_List, ONLY : Link_Ptr_Type,Link_Type,List_Type
USE Generic_List, ONLY : LI_Init_List,LI_Add_To_Head,LI_Add_To_Tail,LI_Get_Head,&
     LI_Remove_Head,LI_Get_Next,LI_Associated,LI_Get_Len, LI_destruct

IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE:: Particle_data
    REAL, dimension(2)   :: pos       !! Coordinate dimensionali 
END TYPE Particle_data 

! Definition of the types necessary for the list
TYPE Particle_Node
  TYPE(Link_Type) :: Link
  TYPE(Particle_data), pointer :: Data  
END TYPE Particle_Node

TYPE Particle_Node_ptr
  TYPE(Particle_Node), pointer :: P
END TYPE Particle_Node_ptr

! Create array of lists in order to allow classify the particles
TYPE(List_Type), allocatable      :: ao_Particle_List(:)
TYPE(Link_Ptr_Type)  :: Link
TYPE(Particle_Node_ptr)  :: Particle_elem

!-------------------------------------------------------------!
!-------------------------------------------------------------!

INTEGER, parameter :: Npart_test = 1000000  ! , nPart
INTEGER :: i,iter,j,item,nBuffer
REAL :: pos(2)

    nBuffer = 5

    IF (ALLOCATED(ao_Particle_List)) DEALLOCATE(ao_Particle_List)
    ALLOCATE(ao_Particle_List(0:nBuffer))  

    ! Init list used for temporary construction
    DO iter=0,nBuffer
        CALL LI_Init_List(ao_Particle_List(iter))
    ENDDO

    DO j=1,NBuffer
        DO i=1,Npart_test
            pos(1)=i*1.0;  pos(2)=j*i

            ALLOCATE(Particle_elem%P); ALLOCATE(Particle_elem%P%Data)   ! Allocate data before store
            Particle_elem%P%Data%pos = pos

            ! Elem is treated and should be put at head of the list ao_Particle_List(item)
            item=j
            Link = TRANSFER(Particle_elem,Link); CALL LI_Add_To_Head(Link,ao_Particle_List(item)) ! STORAGE
        END DO
    END DO

    WRITE(*,*) "List is full, see RAM"; READ(*,*)


    ! Write(*,*) "Destruct list"
    DO iter=0,nBuffer
        CALL LI_Destruct(ao_Particle_List(iter))  
    ENDDO

    IF (ALLOCATED(ao_Particle_List)) DEALLOCATE(ao_Particle_List)
    WRITE(*,*) "List is empty, see RAM";     READ(*,*)

END PROGRAM
```

Thanks to all,
John

Comment: What is your evidence that the memory isn't freed?  You also ask why the memory isn't "emptied".   A deallocate doesn't erase memory, it just informs the memory management system that the memory is available for reuse.

Comment: I check the RAM associated to the process after the list is created and after the list is "destructed", and there is no change. When I run the test in a cycle (as it is in my final application), I see that the RAM usage is going up (up to swap). When I Allocate/Deallocate other kind of data, I never notice this increase of RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem is solved. As there is a transfer operation it seems that the data cannot be reached in the function `LI_DESTRUCT` done.

The correct way to deallocate the linked list is (slightly different as the example in fortran wiki) is:

```
DO
    Link = LI_Remove_Head(ao_Particle_List)
    IF(.NOT.LI_Associated(Link))EXIT
    User = TRANSFER(Link,User)
!~                 WRITE(6,*)User%P%Data%Index,User%P%Data%User_Stuff
    DEALLOCATE(User%P%Data)
    DEALLOCATE(User%P)
ENDDO
```